# Failing to install Spark in an existing laravel project

Tags: laravel, git, github, composer-php, laravel-spark

I have an existing laravel project where I want to install spark.
I have a spark licence.
When I add the following in composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://spark-satis.laravel.com"
    }
],
```

And add the following dependency in composer.json's require section

```
"laravel/spark-aurelius": "~7.0",
```

The next step is to run `composer update` : During this process I provide token generated from github and it is where the installation fails with the following message:

```
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download laravel/spark-aurelius from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark-aurelius/zipball/15585c1e0407623cb218f556144928a380949e9c" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Now trying to download from source
```

And composer fails to clone the github repo (laravel-/spark-aurelius)

This exception is thrown

`[RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git" "C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius" && cd
   /D "C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius" && git remote add composer "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git" && git fetch com
  poser`

How can I fix this issue

Comment: Did you check your git repo path is correct ?

Comment: what happens if you try to run the git clone by your own. you may get a more specific error

Comment: This repo `https://github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius` does not exist 404 is returned